# Angular2 datatables

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable

I'm using [angular2-data-table](https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table). I need to add column with checkboxes, and row must be selected by clicking on checkbox. How can i add that column?

Comment: by coding .....

Comment: useful comment)

Comment: In actual fact the docs are rubbish that project, so I don't think the downvote is fair, personally i'd find another table project to use, try agGrid as their documentation is very good. As a tip though if you post on stack at least try and show some research and some code you've already worked with.

Comment: The angular material guys are working on data table probably we will get the md-data-table soon https://github.com/angular/material2/projects/9
The link is expirable

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above the problem with that repo is it has virtually no docs, agGrid is what you want and the docs are very good.

https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php

Answer (score 0):

If you set selectionMode="multiple" on PrimeNG DataTable, it will give you checkboxes. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/selection